# Discounts the whole products belongs to category?

Tags: php, laravel

I have these tables:

```
products
-- name
-- price
-- quantity
-- category_id

discounts
-- type('percentage','numeric')
-- value
-- expired_at

categories 
-- name

discountables
-- discount_id
-- discountable_id
-- discountable_type
```

In `discountables` there is many to many relationship between:

`discounts and categories` **also** `discounts and products`

I'm done with how to discount between `discounts and products`

Now I'm confused How to discount the whole products that belongs to category that I add to`discountables`

Relation:

Category Models

```
public function discounts()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Discount', 'discountable');
}
```

Products Models

```
public function discounts()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Discount', 'discountable');
}
```

Discount Model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Category', 'discountable')->withTimestamps();
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Product', 'discountable')->withTimestamps();
}
```

MY code for discount the products directly `discounts and products`

```
  /**
 * get price of product after discount
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function getDiscountProductAttribute() {
    foreach ($this->discounts as $discount) {
        if($discount->expired_at > Carbon::now()){
            if ($discount->type == 'numeric'){
                return $this->price - $discount->value;
            }else{
                return $this->price - ($this->price * ($discount->value / 100));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I need  How to discount the whole products that belongs to category that I add to`discountables`?

Comment: What if the product has multiple categories, and at least (2) of those categories have discounts? how do you determine the hierarchical discount application pattern in that case?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy NO my E-commerce is each product has just one category

Comment: And if both the product and the category have discounts?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy that's what exactly my question! discounts for products I handled and everything is fine, Now I need one thing that I don't know how dealing with it. put discount on all products except products had already discount !

Comment: @Ohgodwhy + feel free If you have something better than I'm had done, please suggest it to me with thankful :)

Answer (score 0):

Your relationships are fine. I just redesign a bit to solve the problem.

```
class Discount extends Model
{
    /**
    * Check whether this discount is expired.
    *
    * return bool
    */
    public function expired()
    {
        // I assume that expired_at is also a Carbon instance.
        return $this->expired_at->isPast();
    }

    /**
    * Return the discount amount for each product.
    *
    * @return double
    */
    public function apply(Product $product)
    {
        if ($this->type === 'numeric') {
            $this->value;
        }

        if ($this->type === 'percentage') {
            return $product->price * ($this->value / 100);
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function allDiscounts()
    {
        return $this->discounts
            ->merge($this->category->discounts)
            ->unique();
    }

    pubic function getTotalDiscountAttribute()
    {
        return $this->allDiscounts()
            ->reject
            ->expired()
            ->map
            ->apply($this)
            ->sum();
    }

    public function getTotalPriceAttribute()
    {
         return $this->price - $this->total_discount;
    }
}
```

So you can get the total price for a single product after applying all sort of discounts from itself and its category (if there's any) by simply saying:

```
$product->total_price;
```

I hope that helps. Let me know if it fails at any step.

By the way. Your question reminds me of a [pretty good speech](https://youtu.be/5DVDewOReoY) a few years back. Its about solving a some what similar problem using inheritance and Null Object Pattern. It's pretty cool. You don't need to rewrite it that way but its a pretty good design.

Comment: Can I get some mins?  and continue in live chat?

Comment: I got this error: Trying to get property 'reject' of non-object

Comment: I forgot to return inside the allDiscounts() function. I have updated my answer. Pls try again.

Comment: Worked, but return the price without any discount!

Comment: Pls could you check my answer a little thing left to fix the problem!

Comment: Pls open Laravel Tinker and check the public functions/attributes that I created one by one. I might miss something.

Comment: I found it: in apply fun return in first if | Everything is fine now with discount BUT  one issue left: when the product already has discount I need to avoid the product that already has discount!

Comment: Just for more info: the issue like when I add discount on some random products then I add discount on some categories, one of this category has product and that product already I gave him discount from first discount! ( I need to avoid this product )